# How to publish Gitbook in Dark mode

Tags: gitbook

Is it possible to publish Gitbook in Dark mode.
Gitbook provides option to set dark mode in user settings. But I would like to set dark mode by default for everyone.

Answer (score 5):

You can click on Customize -> General -> Theme mode

Currently, there is an option to only select between light and dark.

[image]

[image]